# Find all files in a directory with an extension, and allow user to choose one to be set to a variable in TCL

Tags: tcl

I have a TCL script running from a directory where a variable amount of .txt files can be. I know that the following TCL command returns all .txt files in the current directory -

```
    glob *.txt
```

However, in the case there is more than one text file, I need the user to choose which file to set a variable name equal to that file name.

For example, suppose in a directory I have

```
    info1.txt
    info2.txt
    info3.txt
```

I need there to be a way for the user to choose one of those files to set VAR equal to the filename.

I also know that in this case, glob *.txt output would be:

```
    info1.txt info2.txt info3.txt
```

I am just stumped on how to achieve this because I am new to TCL. I was thinking maybe have the user press 1 for file1, 2 for file2, and so on since they are separated by a whitespace in the output of glob *.txt

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some example code for getting standard input and reading a file.  The command you're looking for is "gets".

glob.tcl

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set files [glob *.txt]

set len [llength $files]
if {$len == 0} {
        puts "no files"
} elseif {$len == 1} {
        puts "found 1 file. [lindex $files 0]"
} else {
        for {set i 1} {$i <= $len} {incr i} {
                puts "${i}. [lindex $files $i-1]"
        }
        puts "Enter file number to view or 'q' to quit."
        while {[set n [gets stdin]]  != "q"} {
                if {[catch {set filename [lindex $files $n-1]} err] || $filename == ""} {
                        puts "Error selecting #${n}."
                } else {
                        set fp [open $filename r]
                        set file_data [read $fp]
                        close $fp
                        puts "Contents of ${filename}."
                        puts $file_data
                        break
                }
        }
}
```

Output:

```
./glob.tcl
1. test.txt
2. test2.txt
3. test3.txt
4. test4.txt
Enter file number to view or 'q' to quit.
a
Error selecting #a.
q
% ./glob.tcl
1. test.txt
2. test2.txt
3. test3.txt
4. test4.txt
Enter file number to view or 'q' to quit.
1
Contents of test.txt.
hello world
hello world2
```

Comment: Hi this code works great but is there any easy way to implement a while loop for input validation of the user selection? Like if there are 4 possible choices, make sure there input is between 1-4?

Comment: @ChristopherSousa I updated the code with a while loop. As you can see tcl allows for creating and setting the variable in the while condition.

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance. I see the syntax for while loops now in practice. Wish you the best!

Comment: Is there any reason that the while loop doesn't work with numbers outside the range of the number of text files? Im getting an error if the user inputs a number but no error if the user enters characters. Any ideas?

Comment: @ChristopherSousa the filename is blank for indexes out of range so I added a check for empty string.  It should error out on a bad index now.